# Background and NSThread

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background, nsthread

I'm trying to understand how the NSThread is working when the app is going to the background. I have the following code in appdeligate:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application  
{  
    [self backgroundHandler];  
}  

- (void)backgroundHandler {  

    NSInteger counter=0;int scontinue=true;  
    while(scontinue){  
        NSLog(@"counter:%d",counter++);  
        sleep(1)  

    }  
}
```

When I go to the background then it prints out every 1second a value. I have kept it open for about 5min and it gave me:

```
counter:1  
counter:2  
...  
counter:300
```

And this keeps going. However if try to get into the foreground the backgroundHandler doesn't exit the while loop and my app doesn't respond to anything.

Now I change the applicationDideEnterBackground and instead I'm using a thread, i.e.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application  
{  
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(backgroundHandler) toTarget:self withObject:nil];  
}  
- (void)backgroundHandler {  
    NSInteger counter=0;int scontinue=true;  
    while(scontinue){  
        NSLog(@"counter:%d",counter++);  
        //sleep(1) : I remove the sleep for the shake of the example  
    }  
}
```

Although I was expecting to have the same behaviour as in the previous case the thread seems to be hold after some ms. So what I had as a result is:

```
counter:1  
counter:2  
...  
counter:30
```

And now the thread stucks at that point without executing anything. When I go to the foreground then the thread starts running again, i.e. counter increases and it is being printed out. The application runs again normally.

The above example is a rather simplistic version of what I'm tyring to do. What I actually want is when by app goes to the background to communicate with a server as long as the user doesn't go to the foreground. When it goes any communication should be terminated. So what I actually want is a combination of the simple examples above, i.e. when go to background in while loop keep asking the server, and when I enter to the foreground my app start responding normally and terminate the the backgroundHandler for loop.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` is to save the state of the application when the application goes into background. In this if the application starts using a lot of the CPU or RAM, OS will terminate the app based on the state of the phone.

When you want to perform background operations or services to the server enable the background fetch by calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];` in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` of the AppDelegate.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  //Add your code here
 [self setBackgroundCheckInterval:UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData];
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
- (void)setBackgroundCheckInterval:(NSInteger)resultCode
{
    UIBackgroundRefreshStatus status = [UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundRefreshStatus;
    if (status == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusAvailable)
    {
        switch (resultCode)
        {
            case UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed :
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:BACKGROUND_CHECK_INTERVAL_NO_NEW_DATA];
                break;

            case UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData :
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:BACKGROUND_CHECK_INTERVAL_NEW_DATA];
                break;

            case UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData :
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:BACKGROUND_CHECK_INTERVAL_NO_NEW_DATA];
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are these constant variables? 
BACKGROUND_CHECK_INTERVAL_NO_NEW_DATA
BACKGROUND_CHECK_INTERVAL_NEW_DATA
BACKGROUND_CHECK_INTERVAL_NO_NEW_DATA

Comment: Furhtermore, because I'm quite new on that, is it possible to give me a reference/book a complete example to check?

Comment: BACKGROUND_CHECK_INTERVAL_NO_NEW_DATA BACKGROUND_CHECK_INTERVAL_NEW_DATA These are macros that provide the timeValue for the background process to run

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Could this be used to have a constant communication with the server and waiting for different events? For example that within a different system that is connected with the server, something has happened and the iPhone needs to do something?

Comment: you can be dependent on this as the time slots for background are allocated by the OS and if the user uses the app frequently then good number of background sessions are fetched. For handling changes from server that the app needs to react. Please use push notifications.

Comment: @SymeonMattes If this was helpful please give a thumbs up and up vote. Thanks

Comment: Actually this approach is not so useful for my application as I have a long-term poling mechanism. So I need to have a constant communication with the server. Apart from Push Notifications is there anything else I could do?

Comment: You can look into Sockets. http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

The issue with sockets is polling frequency should be handled properly otherwise you might drain the battery